# How can I make Kinesis to use OIDC token to connect to a http endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I plan to use Kinesis firehose to stream data to a HTTP endpoint. The HTTP endpoint is authenticated by OIDC which means it needs a access token to authenticate. But I can't find any place I can put some logic to get access token in firehose. Do I have to use Kinesis data stream and use lambda as consumer to do the job?

Comment: Kinesis Firehouse can only deliver to 4 destinations S3, Redshift, ElasticSearch and Splunk. if data needs to delivered to a HTTP endpoint, sending data to Stream instead of firehouse is a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinesis [Firehouse](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/?nc=sn&loc=1&kinesis-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&kinesis-blogs.sort-order=desc) can deliver events to only 4 destinations S3, Redshift, ElasticSearch and Splunk.

We can [integrate with lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-kinesisfirehose.html) to perform [transformations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) before delivering, which can be used to deliver to other destinations.

However, better choice is to write to kinesis streams instead of firehouse, which can be consumed directly with lambda event source.